# Sending emails with Gmail OAuth2 and SMTP (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, oauth, google-api

I registered my application through the Google API Console. I have a client id, client secret, and have set the redirect URI.

Is there a tutorial or demo for sending email with GMail, OAuth2 and SMTP using JavaScript? I tried searching for but didn't find anything that'll explain the whole process (I cannot use node.js and gmailR).

Comment: You won't be able to do it in the browser if that's what you're asking, the tutorials use node.js because that's got access to SMTP.